# Unable to filter data from knockout view model with drop down selection change

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, linq, knockout.js

I have a simple controller like this:

```
  public JsonResult GetPosts(int? id)
    {
        var varid = id;
        var ret = (from post in db.Posts.ToList()
                   orderby post.PostedDate descending
                   select new
                   { 
                       NeighbourhoodId = varid,
                       Message = post.Message,
                       PostedByName = post.ApplicationUser.UserName,
                       PostedDate = post.PostedDate.ToString(),
                       PostId = post.PostId,
                  });
        return Json(ret, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here, i am able to get the dropdown selected value.I am assigning it to a variable varid and then assigning it to NeighbourhoodId.

But, when the view page is rendered nothing changes all the 4 Post are showing.but in reality it should display only 2 Post.

This is my view page code:

```
<ul id="msgHolder" data-bind="foreach: posts">
<li class="postHolder">
<p><a data-bind="text: PostedByName"></a>: <span data-bind=" html: Message"></span></p>
```

and my wallpost.js file in script folder where all knockout view model related code is here.It first loads all the Post from database correctly but data doesnot get filtered if i am trying to filter it with dropdown change.

```
  function Post(data) {
var self = this;
data = data || {};
self.PostId = data.PostId;
self.NeighbourhoodId = data.NeighbourhoodId;
self.Message = ko.observable(data.Message || "");
self.PostedByName = data.PostedByName || "";

self.PostedDate = getTimeAgo(data.PostedDate);
self.error = ko.observable();

   function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.posts = ko.observableArray();
    self.newMessage = ko.observable();
    self.error = ko.observable();
    self.loadPosts = function () {
        // to load existing posts
        $.ajax({
             url: postApiUrl,
            datatype: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            cache: false,
            type: 'Get'
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            var mappedPosts = $.map(data, function (item)
            { return new Post(item); });
            self.posts(mappedPosts);
        })
        .fail(function () {
            error('unable to load posts');
        });
    }
   return self;
  };
  ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

and my dropdown related code is here:

```
    @Html.DropDownList("Locations", ViewBag.NeighbourhoodId as SelectList,"Select a Location")
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  $(document).ready(function () {
                  $("#Locations").change(function () {
                      var locationSelected = $("#Locations").val();
                      var url = '@Url.Action("GetPosts", "Post")';
                      $.post(url, { id: locationSelected },
                     function (data) {
                         });
                       });
                  });
                </script>
```

When i debug, i am getting correct id value in controller but there is problem in filtering out data. Is there a need for some change in knockout file.what to do here ??

Comment: Show the code of ````Post```` model in **C#**

Comment: public class Post
    {
        public Post()
        {
            this.PostComments = new HashSet<PostComment>();
        }
        [Key]
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public int? NeighbourhoodId { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime PostedDate { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PostComment> PostComments { get; set; }
        public IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
        public virtual Neighbourhood Neighbourhood { get; set; }
    }

Comment: @JoelRamosMichaliszen i have posted full code in comment box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of mixing jquery event handlers and knockout bindings, i think it's better for you handle all with knockout.

1. Bind your select element (drop down) with [the options binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) and load the locations array on view model initialization; bind the value to a observable property, ex: 'CurrentLocation'
2. Subscribe to the change of the property 'CurrentLocation', ex:
       myViewModel.CurrentLocation.subscribe(function(newValue) {
       //request to GetPosts here
   });
3. On .done() function of the GetPosts request update the observableArray with the items received by the server

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE**

The following is a very simple example, i changed my mind and used "event" binding to handle the change event instead of "options" binding but the concept it's the same.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Locations", new SelectList(Model.Locations, "Id", "Name"), new { data_bind = "event: { change: reloadPosts}" })
<ul data-bind="foreach: posts">
    <li data-bind="text:CompleteText"></li>
</ul>


<script>
function Post(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
    self.LocationId = ko.observable(data.LocationId);
    self.Text = ko.observable(data.Text);
    self.CompleteText = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.Id() + " " + self.Text();
    });
}
function PageViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.posts = ko.observableArray();
    self.reloadPosts = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "GetPosts",
            data: { locationId: $("#Locations").val() }
        }).done(function (data) {
            var mappedPosts = $.map(data, function (item)
            { return new Post(item); });
            self.posts(mappedPosts);
        });
    }
}

var vm = new PageViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
</script>
```

The GetPosts method in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetPosts(string locationId)
{
    var selectedPosts = posts.Where(x => x.LocationId == locationId);
    return Json(selectedPosts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The posts collection in the controller in the example above it's just an inmemory collection, probably you will read it from a DB or something like that.

The post class on the c# code:

```
class Post
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string LocationId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }    
}
```

And finally the viewmodel used:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: ballerani Can u put some more code as to how bind selectList options here in my code to a observable property. and then how to use this subcribe fn.I was previously binding directly on view page with the help of view bag through it:  ViewBag.NeighbourhoodId = new SelectList(allNeighbourhood(), "Id", "NeighbourhoodName");

Comment: thnks for the help it was more than enough i got it working with ur help